# connect docker from outside host running virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, odoo-9, docker-swarm

My host machine (main) is Windows 10 
Installed virtual box running Ubuntu 
After starting VM, I installed docker for ubuntu 
Pull images (odoo and postgres) and successfully launch Odoo application via localhost:8069 
I switch back to my main machine which is Windows 10.

How can I connect my odoo application from my Windows 10? 
Also, how can my colleague access my odoo application on the same network?

Hope you can help me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to connect from your windows machine, you can enable port forwarding, by selecting the VM and going to `Settings > Network > Advanced > Port forwarding` and adding an entry with `Host port 8069` and `Guest Port 8069`. 
Now from windows you can connect to `localhost:8069`. In this case, other peers can connect to your machine to access the application `<machine-dns-name>:8069` `<machine-ip>:8069`

Alternatively, you can find the IP address of the Ubuntu VM by running ifconfig and using that ip to connect from windows via `<ubuntu-vm-ip>:8069`